# grouping and divding files which contains numbers in it into saperate folders

Tags: python, linux, bash, sh

I wanted to move the files in group of 30 in sequence starting from image_1,image_2... from current folder to the new folder.

the file name pattern is like below

```
image_1.png
image_2.png
.
.
.
image_XXX.png

I want to move image_[1-30].png to folder fold30
and image[31-60].png to fold60 and so on
```

I have following code to do this and it works wanted to know is there any shortcut to do this.

or is there any smaller code that i can write for the same

```sh
#!/bin/bash
counter=0
folvalue=30
totalFiles=$(ls -1 image_*.png | sort -V | wc -l)
foldernames=fold$folvalue
for file in $(ls -1 image_*.png | sort -V )
do
((counter++))
mkdir -p $foldernames
mv $file ./$foldernames/    
if [[ "$counter" -eq "$folvalue" ]];
then
  let folvalue=folvalue+30
  foldernames="fold${folvalue}"
  echo $foldernames
fi
done
```

the above code moves image_1,image_2,..4..30 in folder

> fold30

image_31,....image_60 to folder

> fold60

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend using `sed` **all** the time. It's hard on the eyes but once you get used to it you can do all these jaring tasks in no time.

What it does is simple. Running `sed -e "s/regex/substitution/" <(cat file)` goes through each line replacing matching patterns `regex` with `substitution`.
With it you can just transform your input into comands and pipe it to bash.
If you want to know more there's good [documentation here](https://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html). (also not easy on the eyes though)

Anyway here's the code:

```
while FILE_GROUP=$(find . -maxdepth 0 -name "image_*.png" | sort -V | head -30) && [ -n "$FILE_GROUP" ]
do
   $FOLDER="${YOUR_PREFIX}$(sed -e "s/^.*image_//" -e "s/\.png//" <(echo "$FILE_GROUP" | tail -1))"
   mkdir -p $FOLDER
   sed -e "s/\.\///" -e "s|.*|mv & $FOLDER|" <(echo "$FILE_GROUP") | bash
done
```

And here's what it should do:
 - `while` loop grabs the first `30` files.
 - take the number out of the last of those files and name the directory
 - `mkdir FOLDER`
 - go through each line and turn `$FILE` into `mv $FILE $FOLDER` then execute those lines (pipe to bash)

**note:** replace `$YOUR_PREFIX`with your folder

**EDIT:** surprisingly the code did not work out of the box(who would have thought...) But I've done some fixing and testing and it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that is with `rename`, a.k.a. `Perl rename`. It will:

- let you run any amount of code of arbitrary complexity to figure out a new name,
- let you do a dry run telling you what it would do without doing anything,
- warn you if any files would be overwritten,
- automatically create intermediate directory hierarchies.

So the command you want is:

```
rename -n -p -e '(my $num = $_) =~ s/\D//g; $_ = ($num+29)-(($num-1)%30) . "/" . $_' *png
```

**Sample Output**

```
'image_1.png' would be renamed to '30/image_1.png'
'image_10.png' would be renamed to '30/image_10.png'
'image_100.png' would be renamed to '120/image_100.png'
'image_101.png' would be renamed to '120/image_101.png'
'image_102.png' would be renamed to '120/image_102.png'
'image_103.png' would be renamed to '120/image_103.png'
'image_104.png' would be renamed to '120/image_104.png'
...
...
```

If that looks correct, you can run it again without the `-n` switch to do it for real.

Comment: it is printing the right sample output after removing option -p , we need to add mkdir -p to create new folders. I have never used Perl I am not sure where i can add the mkdir , I will try to update it if i get any solution , thanks for the help

Comment: Leave the `-p` in and it will make the directories for you. Just remove `-n`.